# Problemas con onAction en JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

estoy aprendiendo JavaFX, pero tengo un problema con onAction, no me aparece la line en el archivo FXML.

```
<Button layoutX="34.0" layoutY="148.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="MOSTRAR"/>
```

Y al añadirla me da como error la linea en donde lo agregue

```
<Button fx:id="butMostrar" onAction="#butMostrar" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="148.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="MOSTRAR"/>
```

Error:

Esta es la clase para realizar la acción.

```
public class Consultas {
    @FXML
    public Button butMostrar;
    public Label res;
    public TextField inCodigo, inNombre, inPrecio, inCantidad;
    
    public void butMostrar(ActionEvent event){
        
        res.setText(inCodigo.getText());
    }
}
```

[image: Esta todo codo configurado en el Scene Builder]

Esta todo codo configurado en el Scene Builder.

Gracias por las respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes agregar la anotación [`@FXML`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXML.html) al método `butMostrar()` del controlador (la clase `Consultas`, que además debe estar definida como el controlador de la vista en el archivo *.fxml*).

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class Consultas {
    @FXML
    public Button butMostrar;
    public Label res;
    public TextField inCodigo, inNombre, inPrecio, inCantidad;
    
    @FXML // <- Sin esta anotación JavaFX no puede encontrar el método del onAction
    public void butMostrar(ActionEvent event){
     
        res.setText(inCodigo.getText());
    }
}
```